# Entity Framework - Model Defined Functions

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to the Entity Framework.

I have a SQL Function that returns the age for a given birthday.
(http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-age.aspx)

And I want to use it with linq. I know it's possible. I've read it here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/01/07/model-defined-functions.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx

but it seems this is part of the EF extentions (which I have) or that it is still in development.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model defined functions are not in the shipping Entity Framework, and I don't think they are in the extensions, either. As far as I know, they are a new feature planned for .NET 4.0. I don't know if they are in the Community Technology Preview of that. You can see a demo of model defined functions if you watch the Entity Framework presentation from PDC. But they are certainly not in .NET 3.5 SP1.

As a workaround, you could define a computed column on your table which used the function and then map that column instead of mapping the function directly.

Comment: I've been looking to see if Model Defined Functions are now available in EF 4.1. Have you found any links discussing that?

Comment: @John, you can do it in EF 4.0+. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456812.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links, Craig. Upon further reading of the production information on these topics, they're not quite what I had in mind. Good to know that they're available, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do a "FunctionImportMapping" see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399203.aspx) for more info..
You could definitley do it that way if you exposed it as a sproc, I've not tried with just a function tho..